# How to get data from array data field in firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my FireStore structure. There are many solutions for it but I'm not getting the correct code for my DB structure.
I want to fetch red marked array

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect, and explain what it's actually doing that's confusing to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
Here is my answer.

```
 docIdRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("Error========", "" + e);
                return;
            }
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                documentSnapshot.getId();
                Map<String, Object> forms = (Map<String, Object>) documentSnapshot.get("resume");
                if (forms != null) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> form : forms.entrySet()) {
                        String key = form.getKey();
                        Log.d("TAG","------------"+key);
                        Object value=form.getValue();
                        Log.d("TAG","-----------"+value);
                        HashMap<String, Object> yourData = (HashMap<String, Object>) form.getValue();
                        Log.d("TAG","-----------"+yourData.get("ResumeName").toString());
                        ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) yourData.get("ResumeURI");
                        Log.d("TAG", "-----------"+list.toString());
                        for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
                        {
                            Log.d("TAG", i+":"+list.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```